# Maven dependency versioning for internal java dependencies

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, versioning, cicd

## Versioning of Internally Developed Dependencies

I'm looking for some examples/ best practices of how other teams are covering this in their projects.

I have a medium sized development team/s who are developing Java applications using Maven as a build tool.

We have a number of dependencies developed in house used by one or more other applications; all using a CI tool to do all the good stuff of running tests and building etc.

My question is around the best practice of the versioning of the internal dependencies in the application POM files.

My instinct is that the CI should build the dependency and tag the git repo when a change has been merged into its main branch and the semver of the package bumped, and if a developer and their application requires that version, then the POM file should be updated as such and the application built with that baked in, using the CI.

That of course would add a greater overhead, rather than just using the latest version of dependencies each time the application build but at least you're targeting exactly what you want for each application; albeit they all may be running different versions of the dependency.

Aside from pushing out security updates, that may not be too undesirable?

My fear is that if two developers are independently developing a feature on the same application and a dependency that there may be a possibility of introducing a regression of a version. Though I imagine this would be caught as a conflict in git or at least should be visible as a change, and it would be the developers responsibility to check the version they are merging isn't older than the current one in the main branch.

I guess I'm just after some pointers on what others are doing with multiple devs changing apps and their devs concurrently.

Generally after some examples of what others are doing.

Comment: On the consuming side you should go and do automatically upgrading those dependencies like Dependabot/Renovate do... that will remove the burden to upgrade manually ...

Answer (score 0):

In general, what you are asking/talking about sounds so obvious, that there is nothing to discuss. My two cents:

1. most probably, the idea about releasing new version upon integrating pull request into branch won't work, the reasoning is following:

   in order to release new version you need to change the value `<version>` of element in `pom.xml`, `maven-release-plugin` performs that in two commits: first one changes `-SNAPSHOT` (current development version) to "release" and the second one changes "release" to `-SNAPSHOT` (next development version), such behaviour of `maven-release-plugin` is reasonable, however, you may face with the following "issues":

   - a lot of noise in commit history from `maven-release-plugin`
   - `maven-release-plugin` will conflict with simultaneous integrations, basically it will fail to commit into stale branch

   we prefer to release intermediate versions (`pre-release`/`build` in semver terms) for such cases (either automatically or on demand), something like:

```bash
 mvn -e --batch-mode -Prelease release:clean release:prepare \
  -Darguments='-DaltReleaseDeploymentRepository=... -DaltSnapshotDeploymentRepository=... -DskipTests=true' \ 
  -DreleaseVersion=X.Y.Z-BUILDNO \
  -DdevelopmentVersion=X.Y.Z-SNAPSHOT \
  -DpushChanges=false \
  -DpreparationGoals="clean deploy"
```

2. the most challenging part is actually a branching strategy: say, the current development version in `develop`/`main` branch is `X.Y.Z-SNAPSHOT`, the question is: "if we are going to release new version of our software what would be the next development version?" (`maven-release-plugin` by default suggests `X.Y.(Z+1)-SNAPSHOT`, however in that case you will fail to release `bugfix` release due to other (possibly conflicting/undesirable) changes in `develop`/`main` branch)